# xlwings - import error

Tags: python, excel, python-3.5, xlwings

Python 3.5 On Mac OS 10.12.2

When importing xlwings module i get a:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    import xlwings
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xlwings/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import _xlmac as xlplatform
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xlwings/_xlmac.py", line 10, in <module>
    import aem
ImportError: No module named 'aem'
```

I have appscript installed already.

Any idea what i am missing here please?

Comment: Can you `import appscript` without issues? Are you sure it's installed in the same python installation as the one you're working on? We recommend to use the Anaconda/miniconda distribution as this saves you from all these issues.

Comment: good point,  although appscript is installed (and Xcode command line)
i could not import appscript:  ImportError: No module named 'appscript'. 

However, i/ve not installed any module with conda and always used pip.  
Any requirement in using conda ?

Comment: it's not a requirement, it just makes things dead simple to install (conda install xlwings). Make sure that appscript is installed properly in the correct location and you're good to go without conda, too.

Comment: My issue is that i need to install some conda package that will allow me to run conda install xlwings since i never installed anything using conda.
Any lead ?

Comment: ok - I think this is none of the above, but rather might be due to Xcode command line tool that needed to be updated:  
in terminal do:   pip unistall appscript, then:   xcode-select --install

Finally, reboot and in terminal do:  pip install xlwings, and voila.

For more info:  
https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=line+code+xcode&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=xcode+command+line+tools+need+to+be+available.

Comment: @CyBu your final comment solution works in 2020